# $sum and $avg not working in aggregation pipeline if using cursor option in MongoDB 3.6

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I was using MongoDB v3.2 and had an aggregation pipeline that would $sum three properties from each document and then do an $avg of these sums. When I updated to v3.6, I was required to use the cursor option. So I set it by adding the following code to my pipeline in mongoose:

```
.allowDiskUse(true)
.cursor({ batchSize: 2500, async: true })
```

That's the only change I did. But the value returned by $avg is null after making this change. The rest of the query works fine though.

Can someone provide some insights on why is this failing on using the cursor option?

Comment: What version of mongoose you are using?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet 4.7.0

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Updated mongoose and now I am able to run the query but WITHOUT cursor only. When I use the cursor option, the query gets stuck. This completely blows my mind since using the cursor with mongo3.6 was the whole point!